Vba to set a filter and delete lines on multiple sheets
I am trying to create a file that goes through 135 tabs and filters each tab in Column E as zero and then deletes any lines where the E cell equals 0. My code is listed below, it currently returns the error. " Auto filter method of Range class failed" and it highlights the autofilter line. If the first tab already has a filter on then it deletes the lines i want it to delete but does not remove the filter and gets stuck on this step, it wont move onto the next line. How do make it work on every tab?
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If (ws.Name <> "Data") And (ws.Name <> "Masterlist") And (ws.Name <> "Masterlist2") Then
            With ws
            lRow = .range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                With .range("B1:B" & lRow)
                  .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0"
                  .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End With
                ws.range("$B$1:$E$2500").AutoFilter Field:=1
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Unless this task is time critical the simplest solution to scan the sheet upwards from lrow to 1 and delete the row if col E is 0. Turn screenupdating off/on if needed.

With the Range definition must include the row which is filtered (E).
Also this is in this case the 4th row of the Range.
To remove autofilter from the sheet use it without arguments.
With ws
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
                With .Range("B1:E" & lRow)     'modified
                  .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="0"   'modified
                  .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End With
                ws.Range("$B$1:$E$2500").AutoFilter  'modified
            End With
            


The Field parameter in Autofilter is the column that is being filtered. Because you are starting on column B in your original code, the field should have been 4 instead of 5. I recommend only filtering on the single column when possible to avoid this kind of confusion. Here is a small update to your code that will handle if there are any existing filters to avoid errors. I have commented it for clarity:
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case LCase(ws.Name)  'convert sheet names to lowercase to avoid case matching errors
            Case "data", "masterlist", "masterlist2"   'compare against lowercase sheetnames, if these are the current worksheet then do nothing
            Case Else
                lLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                ws.AutoFilterMode = False   'Remove any existing filters anywhere on the worksheet
                With ws.Range("E1:E" & lLastRow)    'Filter directly on column E
                    .AutoFilter 1, 0                'There's only a single column, so the field must be 1, filter for value 0
                    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete     'No need to specify specialcells, the filter already ensures that so specialcells is redundant
                    .AutoFilter                     'Remove this filter
                End With
        End Select
    Next ws
    
End Sub


Delete Filtered Rows

If you want to delete blank rows, use "" instead of "0".

Sub DeleteZeroRows()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, drg As Range, vrg As Range
    Dim IsSheetFound As Boolean

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        IsSheetFound = False
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Data", "Masterlist", "Masterlist2"
            Case Else: IsSheetFound = True
        End Select
        If IsSheetFound Then
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off autofiltering
            Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' includes headers
            Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' no headers
            rg.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0" ' for blanks use ""
            Set vrg = Nothing ' reset
            On Error Resume Next
                Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off autofiltering
            If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Zero-rows deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub

